# adding log in using facebook option in registration form

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a registration form in my site,where the users submits their personal details such as name,email id,dob,and mobile number to be stored in my database. Now I am in the idea to include the **connect with facebook button**,,by using that link,the user can provide their details by logging into their account. those details can be stored in my database. my expectation looks like this image..help me to implement this
 [image]

Comment: please do some research before asking on stackoverflow, how to login is explained very well in the facebook docs.

Comment: I have created my App id,but still am getting this error--" Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains." help me out to solve this

Comment: you would find plenty of results by just searching for that message on google or stackoverflow. just add a platform in the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide whether you want to use PHP or JavaScript for Facebook's SDK. Then, download the SDK from:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

Here's a "Getting started" guide for PHP:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

And here's the same kind of guide for JavaScript:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript

Here's a part of my code for Facebook Login written with PHP. Note that I'm using CodeIgniter as a framwork for my project:

```
public function registerWithFacebook()
{
        try {

        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated
        $facebook_user_data = $this->facebook->get_user();

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
            print_r($e);
            return false;
        }

        // if we don't have the facebook-user array variable, leave the method
        if (!$facebook_user_data) {
            return false;
        }

        // If we can't get the email, leave the method
        if(!$facebook_user_data['email']) {
            return false;
        }

        // If user is already registered with Facebook, start sessions and redirect user to app home page (exit the method at this point)
        if ($this->facebook_model->facebookUserIdExistsAlreadyInDatabase($facebook_user_data)) {

            $session = $this->user_model->getUserInfo($facebook_user_data['id']);

                $data = array(
                    'user_id'           => $session['user_id'],
                    'name'              => $session['name'],
                    'email'             => $session['email'],
                    'profilepic'        => $session['profilepic'],
                    'loggedin'          => true,
                    );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);    
                redirect(base_url().'home');
                exit();

        }


        // Generate password for new user since you can't get the password from Facebook (obviously)
        $generated_password = random_string('alnum', 8);

        $data = [
        'email'                 => $facebook_user_data['email'],
        'name'                  => $facebook_user_data['name'],
        'password'              => $this->phpass->hash($generated_password),
        'profilepic'            => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_user_data['id'].'/picture?width=160&height=160',
        'user_facebook_id'      => $facebook_user_data['id'],

        ];


        // Insert data to your database
        $new_user = $this->facebook_model->add_facebook_user($data);

        // If new user's data was saved successfully to database, start sessions and redirect user
        if($new_user) {

                $session = $this->user_model->getUserInfo($facebook_user_data['id']);

                $data = array(
                    'user_id'           => $session['user_id'],
                    'name'              => $session['name'],
                    'email'             => $session['email'],
                    'profilepic'        => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_user_data['id'].'/picture?width=160&height=160',
                    'loggedin'          => true,
                    );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);

                redirect(base_url().'home');
        }
}
```

Comment: you really should not use the php sdk for login if it´s not neccessary - which is definitely not the case here. with the javascript sdk you don´t need to redirect the user, it´s the recommended (and easiest) way.

Comment: Sure, I just gave the guy an example with PHP which **can** be used if wanted.

Comment: I have created my App id,but still am getting this error--" Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains." help me out to solve this